# How to enforce dataclass fields' types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

In this code:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class MyClass:
    value: str

obj = MyClass(value=1)
```

the dataclass `MyClass` is instantiated with a value that does not obey the `value` type.

Is there a simple way (using a decorator, an argument in the `dataclass` decorator or library) of enforcing the fields' types so that the last line in my example raises a `ValueError` or something like that? Is there a major downside of enforcing types in this way?

Comment: Python is not typed and will not become typed. If you want to use typechecking try running [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/).

Comment: @Giacomo Doesn't mean you can't enforce types at runtime at all…

Comment: @deceze It means that you have to implement it yourself. The OP was specifically asking for something like "one line/switch" to turn on type checking. this isn't going to happen.

Comment: I created a tiny Python library for this purpose: https://github.com/tamuhey/dataclass_utils

This library can be applied for such dataclass that holds another dataclass (nested dataclass), and nested container type (like `Tuple[List[Dict...`)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can declare a custom `__post_init__` method (see [python's doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing)) and put all checks there to force type checking. This method can be declare in parent's class to reduce changes amount.

```py
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass()
class Parent:
    def __post_init__(self):
        for (name, field_type) in self.__annotations__.items():
            if not isinstance(self.__dict__[name], field_type):
                current_type = type(self.__dict__[name])
                raise TypeError(f"The field `{name}` was assigned by `{current_type}` instead of `{field_type}`")

        print("Check is passed successfully")


@dataclasses.dataclass()
class MyClass(Parent):
    value: str


obj1 = MyClass(value="1")
obj2 = MyClass(value=1)
```

The results:

```
Check is passed successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __post_init__
TypeError: The field `value` was assigned by `<class 'int'>` instead of `<class 'str'>`
```

Comment: this only checks the annotations of the current class not from any parents. Better to use the `dataclasses.fields` instead

Comment: Note that this doesn't work when importing `annotations` from `__future__`, then the `type` field becomes a string for builtin types

Comment: Nice, and helpful. I needed to modify my types to avoid parameterized generics because `isinstance(["this"],list[str])` is not valid.